# Multiprocessing Synchronization

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Let's suppose I need to run 5 processes in parallel but processes 2 to 5 are dependent on process one. How can I make sure process 1 will run before the others? Should I use Python's Multiprocessing Event() or Lock() or both?

Example 1:

```
process 1
process 2 or 3 or 4 or 5
process 2 or 3 or 4 or 5
process 2 or 3 or 4 or 5
process 2 or 3 or 4 or 5
```

Example 2:

```
process 3
process 1 or 2 or 4 or 5
process 1 or 2 or 4 or 5
process 1 or 2 or 4 or 5
process 1 or 2 or 4 or 5
```

Example3 with 2 dependencies:

```
process 1
process 2 or 3 (run in parallel after 1)
process 4
process 5 or 6 (run in parallel after 1 and after 4)
```

All processes call the same function(msg) but all return different values.

I need some guidance, not necessarily code, if you can provide, thanks.

Pseudo-code:

```
import Multiprocessing as mp

function(msg):
    return 1 if msg == "one"
    return 2 if msg == "two"
    return 3 if msg == "three"
    return 4 if msg == "four"
    return 5 if msg == "five"

msgs = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

jobs = []
for msg in msgs:
    p = Process(target=function, args=(msg,))
    p.start()
    jobs.append(p)

for job in jobs:
    job.join()
```

In this case all processes will run unordered.

If I want process 1 before I could do:

Possible solution:

```
import Multiprocessing as mp

function(msg):
    return 1 if msg == "one"
    return 2 if msg == "two"
    return 3 if msg == "three"
    return 4 if msg == "four"
    return 5 if msg == "five"

msg = ['one']
p1 = Process(target=function, args=(msg,))
p1.start()
p1.join()


msgs = ['two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

jobs = []
for msg in msgs:
    p = Process(target=function, args=(msg,))
    p.start()
    jobs.append(p)

for job in jobs:
    job.join()
```

Is there a better solution or like this is fine?  It works, but it doesn't mean it can't be done in a better way (less code repetition for example).

Comment: Just spawn the processes after 1, when 1 finishes?

Comment: I did that, but doesn't seem the best solution since it creates boilerplate code. What if is process number X that should come first or second? I was looking for a more generic solution using multiprocessing. I will take a look at semaphores.

Comment: So simply not-starting two processes until they are ready to go is "boilerplate", but starting them and having to wait immediately on some half-externally, half-internally managed lock/semaphore is compact design? Hint: no, it is not.

Comment: I see your point but I finally manage to do with Lock() and the code is cleaner than repeating the call in my opinion. I think this depends on each case. Anyway, good to know that it's not considered bad design to do as you (@tevemadar) and @Josua Nixon advised. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what was done at the end, but you can use `Event`s for this purpose after all:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def function(msg,events):
  if msg == "one":
    print(1)
    events[0].set()
  if msg == "two":
    print("2 waiting")
    events[0].wait()
    events[1].wait()
    print("2 done")
  if msg == "three":
    print(3)
    events[1].set()
  if msg == "four":
    print(4)
  if msg == "five":
    print("5 waiting")
    events[0].wait()
    print("5 done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  events = [mp.Event(),mp.Event()]
  jobs = []
  for item in ['one','two','three','four','five']:
    job = mp.Process(target=function, args=(item,events))
    job.start()
    jobs.append(job)
  for job in jobs:
    job.join()
```

Here I deliberately introduced a second dependency: p2 depends on both p1 and p3 (and p5 still depends on p1). This way if you run it a couple times, it shows more variation (than with a single dependency):

> ```
> python procy.py
> 2 waiting
> 4
> 1
> 5 waiting
> 5 done
> 3
> 2 done
>
> python procy.py
> 1
> 5 waiting
> 2 waiting
> 4
> 5 done
> 3
> 2 done
>
> python procy.py
> 1
> 4
> 3
> 5 waiting
> 5 done
> 2 waiting
> 2 done
> ```

Comment: Thank you tevemadar. Your code is clear and concise, just what I was looking for. I did with lock, but your code is much more clear.